# regex for all text before letter and number combination

Tags: .net, regex

I need a regular expression to capture all text before a character, lower or upper case directly followed by a number from zero to nine. And if the code would be different the same but for more than one character in both lower or upper case. An example of the type of strings I am working with:

`case 1: "This is what I want v1"`

`case 2: "This is what I want Vol.27"`

`desired result: This is what I want`

I have it working except for being case insensitive:

`result = Regex.Match(filename, @"(.*?)(?:\s+V[0-9]+|\s+Vol\.?\s*[0-9]+)").Groups[1].Value;`

So close! Anyone know how to make it case insensitive?

Comment: Does case 2 also match? It has a `.` in addition to letters and numbers. If so what other characters are legal as well and under  what constraints?

Answer (score 0):

One or more numbers can be represented by the set:

```
[0-9]+
```

So what you want is

```
[\s\w]+[^0-9]
```

This says [\s\w]+ - one or more *whitespace* character or *word* character not followed by any number 0 through 9.

[check it out here](https://regex101.com/r/eq0ePl/1)

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that maybe you want a bit more bounded expression, such as:

```
(.*?)(?:\s+v[0-9]+|\s+vol\.?\s*[0-9]+)
```

with an `i` flag.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/s0iKQP/1/)

#### [.NET DEMO](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28.*%3f%29%28%3f%3a%5cs%2bv%5b0-9%5d%2b%7c%5cs%2bvol%5c.%3f%5cs*%5b0-9%5d%2b%29&i=This+is+what+I+want+v1%0d%0aThis+is+what+I+want+Vol.27%0d%0aThis+is+what+I+want+vol+1%0d%0aThis+is+what+I+want+VOL.+27&r=%5c1&o=im)

Comment: This is perfect! However I can't seem to get it to work in .Net. I just need the syntax of this exact thing to work in .Net.

Comment: I am still struggling, I'm not sure what an i flag is. So my code is now thus:

Regex.Replace(filename, @"((.*?)(?:\s+v[0-9]+|\s+vol\.?\s*[0-9]+))", "\\1")

This selects the entire string though.